# python import error when importing zmq

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I have a zmq directory in cwd . when i import zmq from a python file running under apache it gives me import error. but when i import zmq using console from current directory it imports.

How to make this import possible from anywhere in my server?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that zmq is installed on computer?
If not then try installing it. In ubuntu it is quite easy 
sudo apt-get install python-zmq

Comment: my ubuntu is 10.10 and python is 2.6

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the zmq directory to your path. Inside the Python script you should add something like this:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/absolute/path/to/zmq/directory')
```

Comment: i tried that still its giving me import error. but when i open python console from current directory it works.

Comment: It's almost certainly something to do with the path. For debugging purposes you could try doing the above followed by a "print sys.path" and seeing what is in their. You also might want to give us your actual directory structure, the full list of imports and the stracktrace. It might be that you can't import the module you want because something inside that module is failing to import.